# Composer package thinks I'm using an old version of PHP (OSX)

Tags: php, composer-php, osx-elcapitan

In the terminal `php -v` shows :

```
PHP 7.1.8 (cli) (built: Aug 17 2017 11:34:56) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

But while trying to install the following with composer :

```
composer require web-token/jwt-framework
```

I get :

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                                          
Could not find package web-token/jwt-framework in any version 
matching your PHP version (5.5.31.0)
```

I know OSX ships with ancient version of PHP, which is why I updated it a while ago. But does anybody know what is going on here? Why is this package reporting that I'm using v5.5.31.0?

Comment: What does `command -v composer && head -1 $(command -v composer)` show you?

Comment: what version of osx and how did you install the new php ?

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly specifying php while calling composer: `php composer.phar require web-token/jwt-framework`.

`composer` could be an alias with system-installed php. You can check it using `which composer` or `alias composer`

Comment: That will only work if `composer.phar` exists in the cwd. There is no system-installed composer.